# Documenting [Authorize] attribute usage, producing a report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Many classes and methods within my ASP.NET MVC 3 application are decorated with the *[Authorize]* attribute, like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "assignment_edit, assignment_view")] 
public class AssignmentController : Controller {
```

or this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "assignment_edit")]
public ActionResult Create(AssignmentViewModel assignment)
{
```

I'd like to find a way to document what classes and methods are limited to particular roles and users, and produce a report grouped by role or class indicating who is authorized to do what. This would make it easier to know what role to grant to a user if they need to perform certain actions.

I've considered using C#'s built in documentation and using a tag like *[remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zw4z1ys.aspx)* to store this information, then [outputting it into an xml file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3260k4x7.aspx), but it seems clunky -- I'd need to re-type in information which could get out of synch with the attribute, and post-process the XML document to parse the information and present it in a readable form.

I'm curious whether anyone else has had a similar need and whether any tools or processes exist for tackling this problem?

Comment: have you used t4 before?

Comment: Reflection does appear to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tools available,
For example,

To add documentation to your method or class , you can use "[GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx)"

To Create documentation file out of above XML Documentations, you can use "[VSDocMan](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html)"

For free products,

You can use [SandCastle](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=10526)

Answer (score 1):

I use ASP.NET MVC SiteMap provider
http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/
also could find it in Nuget

Set roles In the .sitemap file

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home"  controller="Home" action="Index">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About" roles="Admin,Users"/>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="LogOn" controller="Home" action="LogOn"/&gt
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

And if the request isn't Authenticated

Sitemap.CurrentNode will be null
So i add a ActionFiliter

```
public class RolesAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (SiteMap.CurrentNode == null)
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
        }
    }
}
```

In Controller

```
[RolesAuthenticationAttribute]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, thanks for the suggestion.  While I do use the MVC SiteMap provider to provide navigation within my site, I hadn't thought to use it in combination with a custom attribute to store access privileges in the sitemap file.